# Load same template from different methods

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc

My case looks like this:
I have site with accounts list and an edit button in every row. I have a template which is form used to create new account. Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = USERS + LECTURER + ADD, method = GET)
    public String userAdd() {
        return ADMINISTRATION + USERS + LECTURER + ADD;
    }
```

I want to use the same template to edit user, but I have method which first recognize if user is for ex. LECTURER or STUDENT:

```
@RequestMapping(value = USERS + "/{userId}" + EDIT, method = GET)
    public String editUser(@PathVariable(value = "userId") final long userId,
            final ModelMap modelMap)
```

Then I want to load all user data (name, surname etc.) into form (USERS+LECTURER+ADD). How can I do it respecting Post/Redirect/Get pattern? I planned to go like this:
(someone clicked edit button) -> go to method mapped USERS/{userId}/EDIT which finds user access level -> (if LECTURER) go to USERS/LECTURER/{idUser}/EDIT and load all data to form (template is in USERS/LECTURER/ADD) -> save modified data and redirect to USERS (users list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I though I can't have 2 methods with same RequestMapping, but it's possible when these methods use different HTTP methods (POST or GET). It solved my problem, because I loaded form in controller method using GET and saved changes using POST (+ redirect). thanks for reply, Martin.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your requestmapping method returns a string (or modelandview) you can return whatever template reference you like. The returned string will be used by spring to resolve the template. 
Take a look at the spring documentation about requestmapping. Its quite well explained there.